# How to set production mode on the dashboard in a self hosted parse-server setup

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

[image: Parse dev mode]

I have tried setting `NODE_ENV=production` or `production: true` in js config. But the dashboard still shows `DEV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

production mode doesn't mean anything in self hosted parse-server.  Having said that, if you want the dashboard icon to turn green, you can set it in the parse-dashboard config by just setting `production: true` for that app that you want to have green.

It's spelled out in the [docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard#other-configuration-options)

you can set [custom icons](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard#app-icon-configuration) too....cool